# How to turn values from a query result into variable and variable value?

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to pull two columns from my database and turn the column1 value into the variable name and the value from column2 into the variable value.
Like this:

column1 | column2

value1  | value2

value3  | value4

```
The result should be: 
$value1 = "value2"
$value3 = "value4"
etc..
```

Is there any way to achieve this with one singe query?

Comment: no query can do that, you'll have to do that on PHP side

Comment: show us your DB connection code (not the username/pwd) and how you typically make queries and retrieve results so we have a better idea of the context in which to provide a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it by php code,

$query = "SELECT col1, col2 FROM test";

if($result = mysqli_query($conn, $query)) {

```
/* fetch associative array */
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    ${$row['col1']} = $row['col2'];
}

echo $val1;     // Echos val2
echo "<br />";
echo $val3;     // Echos val4
/* free result set */
mysqli_free_result($result);
```